# Multilingual implementation in buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual, buddypress

i’m working on the wordpress and buddypress. I was easily implemented the multilingual for wordpress but it’s really very hard to implement for buddypress.

I gone through most of the forums, most of the people said buddypress multiligual plugin only works for Wordpress Multisite. Is it any way to enable the multilingual for buddypress or already any plugin exists for this task??

I tried the buddypress multilingual lpugin too. But it's not supporting!! Please leave your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem some weeks ago. I'm sorry but you've three options:

- Consider modify the Buddypress ML plugin in order to get it working: That's modify every line of code that's not working for the last version of Buddypress and fixing it. It's a lot of work but, for sure, the most valuable option. You can ask for help for this in the community of Buddypress because there're a lot of people searching for it.
- Make it multilingual only the labels
  and not the post (that can be easy
  done modifying your wp-config.php to
  get the GET parameter and loading the
  needed file of location:

  if ( isset($_GET['lan']) && $_GET['lan'] == 'es')
      define ('WPLANG', 'es_ES');

The problem with that is you only get located the labels of the website and not the content, obviously, but I think in a community like Buddypress almost all the content is generated by the user so they will write it in his language and you don't have to worry about translate it. (is like Facebook, labels of the site translated but not the content).

- Finally, make a blog for each language and
  make manual links between them: What about that? Well if Wordpress can do now multisite, you can create a blog for, for example, the Spanish content and another for the English. You will must to hyperlink each post with his translation but may be a easy solution for your problem.

Sorry for my bad english, I'm Spanish but I hope you understand it.

Comment: Hi miduga,  Thanks for your reply. But could you make me clear. I can able to understand what you said in the 3 points. But i need more clarification on it. I want it in detail. Could you help me??

Comment: Yep, I've update it with more information. Sorry for my english I hope you can get it working!!

Comment: thanks for your extreme reply. I have to check all the 3 options. And more over i'm also poor in english. So it's not at all a pbm for me! Cool!!

Comment: hi miduga, thanks for the reply. And it's working awesome , i followed your 3rd option.

Comment: Great! ;) I'm glad my comment was useful!